# How do I check for last loop iteration in Django template?

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I have a basic question, in the Django template language how can you tell if you are at the last loop iteration in a `for` loop?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You would use [`forloop.last`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for). For example:

```
<ul>
{% for item in menu_items %}
    <li{% if forloop.last %} class='last'{% endif %}>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: If there are nested loops, will it check the inner-most loop?

Comment: Is this a feature of a newer Jinja version? Getting "rendering template: 'forloop' is undefined" on {% if not(forloop.last) %} , {% endif %}

Comment: If there are nested loops, use `forloop.parentloop` to access the loop surrounding the current one. So to check for the last iteration of a parent loop, one could use `forloop.parentloop.last`. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

@Tagar

Comment: So, in short, `forloop.last` will check for the last iteration of the inner-most loop.

Answer (score 14):

{{ forloop.last }}

Answer (score 2):

You can basically use this logic in a `for` loop:

```
{% if forloop.last %}
   # Do something here
{% endif %}
```

For example, if you need to put a comma after each item except for the last one, you can use this snippet:

```
  {% for item in item_list %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
        {{ item }}
    {% else %}
         {{ item }},
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

which will become for a list with three items:

```
first_item, second_item, third_item
```